# Python filter out empty strings on join

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string that I need to concatenate with a '|' in the user interface. For example:

```
'Walkable  Close to Transit  HOA Fee Free'
```

So far I have:

```
' | '.join(row['notes'].split('  '))
```

For some reason, if there is only one value in the string (e.g. 'Walkable 
 ') I get `'Walkable |'` when I need `'Walkable'`.

I also tried:

```
' | '.join(filter(None, row['notes'].split('  ')))
```

However, I get `filter undefined error`. I am using Python 2.7. Any ideas on how I might get this to work?

Comment: Splitting a string will not produce `None` but it might produce an empty string: `''` ;)

Comment: `filter` is a builtin function in `python 2.7`. The error must be somewhere else. If you post full stack trace of error it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The filter None should work but one can use the equivalent generator expression:

```
' | '.join(part for part in row['notes'].split('  ') if part)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though I left out some important information: the error was being thrown in a Jinja template. By moving the concatenation into my `app.py` as follows it worked:

```
def format_notes(value):
    values = value.split('  ')
    return ' | '.join(filter(None, values))
```

In my template:

```
{{row['notes']|format_notes if row['notes'] != None}}
```

Thanks to @bro-grammer for the hint.